# Touchpad not working in RHEL 7.4 for Dell vostro

Tags: linux, rhel, touchpad

Not able to find a way to make my touchpad work again. It was working fine in Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS but when upgraded to RHEL 7.4 it stopped working.

Laptop - Dell Vostro 3468

Things which i tried

- Verified that it is enabled in Settings > Hardwarde > Touchpad
- Verified the driver is installed. Both xorg-x11-drv-synaptics and kcm_touchpad.x86_64 are installed and are updated.
- After reading some of the answers made some changes in 50-synaptics.conf file. I'm keeping this file at both the locations /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d and /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/ as don't know the overriding sequence.

50-synaptics.conf looks like this : -

```
    Section "InputClass"
    Identifier "touchpad catchall"
    Driver "synaptics"
    Option  "TapButton1"  "1"
    Option  "VertEdgeScroll"  "1"
    Option "RBCornerButton" "3"
    MatchIsTouchpad "on"
    MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
    EndSection
```

Comment: try installing `libinput` instead of `synaptics`, another situation could be having external kernel modules altering your driver setup... but first try `libinput` if that does not work, you need to see which driver is using synaptics in `lsmod`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following worked for me

1) Add i8042.nopnp to grub command line in /etc/default/grub:

## change this:

```
   GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="... quiet"
```

## to:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="... quiet i8042.nopnp"
```

2) Update your grub config (as root):

## If you're using UEFI boot

```
grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/efi/EFI/centos/grub.cfg
```

3) Blacklist module i2c_hid (as root):

```
echo "blacklist i2c_hid" > /etc/modprobe.d/i2c-hid.conf
```

4) Regenerate your initramfs (as root):

```
cp -v /boot/initramfs-$(uname -r).img /boot/initramfs-$(uname -r).img.bak
dracut -f
```

5) Reboot!